# Creating an OR statement using existing conditions hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a problem where I need to add an OR clause to a set of existing conditions. The current conditions are built in a hash in a method and at the end, they are used in the where clause. Here is a simplified example:

```
...
conds.merge!({:users => {:archived => false}})

Model.where(conds)
```

I am trying to add an OR clause to the current set of conditions so it would be something like '(conditions) OR new_condition'. I'd like to add the OR statement without converting each addition to the conds hash into a string. That would be my last option. I was hoping someone has done something like this before (without using Arel). I seem to recall in Rails 2 there was a way to parse a conditions hash using a method from the model (something like `Model.some_method(conds)` would produce the where clause string. Maybe that would be a good option to just add the OR clause on to that string. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I needed. Instead of changing all of the conditions that I am building, I am parsing the conditions to SQL using sanitize_sql_for_conditions. This is a private method in ActiveRecord, so I had to put a method on the model to allow me to access it. Here is my model method:

```
def self.convert_conditions_hash_to_sql(conditions)
  self.sanitize_sql_for_conditions(conditions)
end
```

So, once I convert my conditions to text, I can add my OR clause (along with the appropriate parentheses) to the end of the original conditions. So, it would go something like this:

```
Model.where('(?) OR (model.type = ? AND model.id IN(?))', Model.convert_conditions_hash_to_sql(conds), model_type, model_id_array)
```